# html slideshow isn't displaying images correctly

Tags: html, css, image, slideshow

I'm an IT student in year 11 and I am struggling with adding a slideshow of images to my website I'm working on, I have tried looking up solutions but I can't seem to find anything that fixes my problem.

When I run the webpage in chrome, everything appears to be there, but the images aren't contained in the slideshow container, they run down the page.

I'm afraid it might be a really simple solution as I am still learning, but I would really appreciate if someone is able to figure out what is wrong as this is due soon and I'm running out of options. I got the code from w3schools.

Below is the code in my html document:

```
<!-- Slideshow container -->
<div class="slideshow-container">

<!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
<img src="images/max_photos.jpg" style="width:100%"/>
<div class="text">Caption Text</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
<img src="images/max_chloe.jpg" style="width:100%"/>
<div class="text">Caption Two</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
<img src="images/pictures.jpg" style="width:100%"/>
<div class="text">Caption Three</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
<img src="images/trains.jpg" style="width:100%"/>
<div class="text">Caption Three</div>
</div>

<!-- Next and previous buttons -->
<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>

<!-- The dots/circles -->
<div style="text-align:center">
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>
```

And the css code:

```
* {box-sizing:border-box}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
max-width: 1000px;
position: relative;
margin: auto;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
display: together;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
width: auto;
margin-top: -22px;
padding: 16px;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 18px;
transition: 0.6s ease;
border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
right: 0;
border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through 
*/
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
color: #f2f2f2;
font-size: 15px;
padding: 8px 12px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 8px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
color: #f2f2f2;
font-size: 12px;
padding: 8px 12px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
cursor:pointer;
height: 15px;
width: 15px;
margin: 0 2px;
background-color: #bbb;
border-radius: 50%;
display: inline-block;
transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
-webkit-animation-name: fade;
-webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
animation-name: fade;
animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
from {opacity: .4} 
to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
from {opacity: .4} 
to {opacity: 1}
}
```

I've never posted to this site before, I hope I've included everything needed.

Comment: Where is currentSlide(n) function

Comment: @Anuresh I don't know, where should it be inserted?

Comment: Check this link https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_slideshow_dots

Comment: @Anuresh I'm pretty sure I already have, is the java script necessary? Because I'm not allowed to use it.

Comment: Without function currentSlide(),how will this work onclick="currentSlide(1)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added any JavaScript for this slideshow? I guess not. Probably you wanted to follow w3school. 
You need to have JavaScript code to show one image at a time and hide others
You have a ready made example for the same code you have written follow the link:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow

Comment: Thank you! It is working well now, I understand why JavaScript was needed.